# Netbeans Working directory error

Tags: java, netbeans, working-directory

I'm new to NetBeans and I need a little help with it.

I am trying to start my homework, however, I've run into a bit of a problem. **Please note that I am NOT asking for help with the assignment itself nor am I asking for anybody to do my homework for me. I am simply trying to solve an unexpected issue with NetBeans.**

Assignment:
http://www.cs.stonybrook.edu/~cse219/hw/HW2.html

With that said, Everything seems to be working correctly until I get up step 9 of the assignment. The GUI fails to load when I try to run the application and instead I am plagued with a bunch of errors shown in the link below:

Errors: http://pastebin.com/udA5rpE2

*****************************EDIT************************************************

Looking at the error message, it seems like Netbeans is confusing my working directory with that of my professor's. So it seems to assume that his directory is within my directory. I edited the run.xml file with purely my directory and it works fine. However, I do not think it's such a good idea to hardcode a directory like this. Is there an alternative?

I've tried the solution at the link below, which does work. However, the images on the JButtons do not load when taking that approach. Instead, I am stuck with tiny, empty buttons.

Proposed Solution: http://forums.netbeans.org/ntopic45961.html

To summarize what's going on, I've made a YouTube video to illustrate the problem.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9XcLmk5x5TM&feature=youtu.be